# Using libarchive in Qt - build errors

Tags: c++, qt, archive, tar

I've got hold of [libarchive](http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/) and built the examples on both Windows and Linux following the [build instructions](http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/wiki/BuildInstructions).

I now want to use this library in my project, which is Qt based, so I'm using Qt creator. I've added the include paths for libarchive in my pro file, but when I compile I get errors saying "undefined reference to '*imp*_archive_read_new'" and so on.

This is my code at the moment:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include "archive.h"
    #include "archive_entry.h"

    cTarFileManager::cTarFileManager()
    {
      struct archive *a;
      struct archive_entry *entry;
      int r;
      int64_t entry_size;
      a = archive_read_new();
      archive_read_support_compression_none(a);
      archive_read_support_format_tar(a);
      r = archive_read_open_filename(a, "0000.tar", 1024);
      if (r != ARCHIVE_OK)
      {
        printf("archive not found");
      }
      else
      {
        while (archive_read_next_header(a, &entry) == ARCHIVE_OK)
        {
          const char *currentFile = archive_entry_pathname(entry);
          char *fileContents;
          entry_size = archive_entry_size(entry); //get the size of the file
          fileContents = (char*)malloc(entry_size); //alloc enough for string - from my testing I see that this is how many bytes tar and ls report from command line
          archive_read_data(a, fileContents, entry_size); //read data into fileContents string for the HTML file size
          if(strcmp(currentFile, "vendar-definition.html") == 0)
          {
            printf("file name = %s, size = %ld\n", currentFile, entry_size);
            printf("%s\n\n", fileContents); //this output over-reads chars from another file in this tar file
          }
          free(fileContents); //free the C string because I malloc'd
        }
      }
      printf("exit");
    }
```

Here is the full list or errors I get:
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:16: undefined reference to `_imp__archive_read_new'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:17: undefined reference to`*imp*_archive_read_support_compression_none'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:18: undefined reference to `_imp__archive_read_support_format_tar'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:19: undefined reference to`*imp*_archive_read_open_filename'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:28: undefined reference to `_imp__archive_entry_pathname'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:30: undefined reference to`*imp*_archive_entry_size'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:32: undefined reference to `_imp__archive_read_data'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:26: undefined reference to`*imp*_archive_read_next_header'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:16: undefined reference to `_imp__archive_read_new'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:17: undefined reference to`*imp*_archive_read_support_compression_none'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:18: undefined reference to `_imp__archive_read_support_format_tar'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:19: undefined reference to`*imp*_archive_read_open_filename'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:28: undefined reference to `_imp__archive_entry_pathname'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:30: undefined reference to`*imp*_archive_entry_size'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:32: undefined reference to `_imp__archive_read_data'
D:\Tar-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Tar/TarFileManager.cpp:26: undefined reference to`*imp*_archive_read_next_header'

Comment: Did you update the library path as well, and link with the library? It's hard to say anything without you posting the actual errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, it's a linking problem. You do not actually link with the library. I don't know how you do it in Qt Creator, but you have to add the flags `-L/path/to/library/folder` and `-lname_of_library` to the linking stage.

Comment: Thanks! I've just this moment managed to link it properly on my Linux system, just need to get it going on Windows now...